# how to include a header file in c

Tags: c, include, include-path

I have some files like: ~/code/include/test.h, ~/code/src/test.c. I use include "test.h" in test.c but the compiler can't find test.h. Is there any way to solve the problem EXCEPT include "../include/test.h"

Comment: What is your build environment? Generally `-I` on the command-line will provide paths.

Comment: Put the header in the same folder as the .c file?

Comment: what compiler do you use? how are you running the compiler? Command-line? IDE? make?

Answer (score 8):

Your compiler, IDE or build system should provide a command-line switch or a property for specifying *additional include directories* for a compile.

With `cc` and variants the switch is `-I`.

How you use this is specific to how you're organizing your builds, but given the directory structure in your question, if you're running `gcc` in `~/code/src/`, then the command-line might look like:

```
gcc -I../include -o test test.c
```

Visual Studio uses *Additional Include Directories* in the Properties dialog under *Configuration Properties->C/C++->General*.